# How do I get a trait to know about the members of it's sub classes in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to find all the internal **case class**es of an **object** which extends a **trait** (MyTrait), but it is not working. The following code works if I had all the code in ChildClassesObject **object**, but that's not what I want as I want all the **object**s extending MyTrait to inherit the childClasses **val**

```
trait MyTrait {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  val childClasses = typeOf[this.type].members.filter(_.isClass)
}

object ChildClassesObject extends MyTrait with App {
  case class User(name: String)
  case class Product(name: String)
  childClasses foreach println
}
```

I've also tried using a companion object and then passing the the type of ChildClassesObject to MyTrait but still doesn't work.

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  def childClasses(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = typeOf[T].members.filter(_.isClass)
}

object ChildClassesObject extends App {
  def apply() = new ChildClassesObject
}

class ChildClassesObject extends MyTrait[ChildClassesObject.type] {
  case class User(name: String)
  case class Product(name: String)
  childClasses foreach println
}
```

I tried a few things but nothing I come up with works and I've had no luck with google so far. Can someone please tell me how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Tell please how are you going to use such class list

Comment: The above example is a very simplified version. In the real code ChildClassesObject has logic where it receives only the className from an external service and childClasses is actually returning Map[simpleClassName: String, fullClassName: String] and using this Map I am applying some JSON string to the fullClassName to get the case class from the JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second version works if you replace `extends MyTrait[ChildClassesObject.type]` with `extends MyTrait[ChildClassesObject]`.

I was able to get your first version to work by using a type member instead of a type parameter:

```
trait MyTrait {
  type T
  def childClasses(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) =
    typeOf[T].members.filter(_.isClass)
}

object ChildClassesObject extends MyTrait {
  type T = this.type
  case class User(name: String)
  case class Product(name: String)
}
```

Perhaps there's a better solution; I'm just fumbling around.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `typeOf[this.type]` gets filled in during compilation of MyTrait, so childClasses will always be an empty list.

```
trait MyTrait {
 import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
 val childClasses = typeOf[this.type].members.filter(_.isClass)
}
```

You can try using java reflection instead:

```
scala> trait MyTrait{
   val innerClasses = this.getClass.getClasses
 }

scala> object ChildClassesObject extends MyTrait with App {
  |     case class User(name: String)
  |     case class Product(name: String)
  | }
defined object ChildClassesObject

scala> ChildClassesObject.innerClasses
res9: Array[Class[_]] = Array(class ChildClassesObject$User, class ChildClassesObject$User$, class ChildClassesObject$Product, class ChildClassesObject$Product$, class ChildClassesObject$delayedInit$body)
```

but this way you will be able to see synthetic inner classes. You can try to filter them: `this.getClass.getClasses.filter(!_.isSynthetic)`